# bessel function math in cylindrical waveguide modes in python

Tags: bessel-functions

In theory shown bellow,we need to find p' which are the roots of the bessel function derivative. its used for cylindrical structure. can i please have an example (maybe in python) on how exactly they got p'03=10.174 in the table bellow? Thanks.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w62cd.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vyaM.png)